# Calculator app not responding on equal button

Tags: android, calculator

In my simple calculator project , when i press the equal button the program exit and it says that my program is not responding. In the android monitor i cannot find any error.The equal button is supposed to see what mathematical operator has been inputted by the user assuming it has been inputted once and after that it get the numerical values before and after this operator and do the required mathematical function. Here is my code :

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    public boolean isEmpty(EditText editText) {
        if (editText.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
Button number9;Button number8;Button number7;Button number6;Button number5;Button number4;Button number3;Button number2;
    Button number1;Button number0;Button numberplus;Button numberminus;Button numbertimes;Button numberdiv;Button numberequal;
    Button numberdecimal;EditText text_;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        number0= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn0);
        number1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        number2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        number3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        number4= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        number5= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
        number6= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn6);
        number7= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn7);
        number8= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn8);
        number9= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn9);
        numberplus= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnplus);
        numbertimes= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btntimes);
        numberminus= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnminus);
        numberequal= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnequal);
        numberdiv= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btndiv);
        numberdecimal=  (Button) findViewById(R.id.btndecimal);
        text_=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        number0.setOnClickListener(this);
        number1.setOnClickListener(this);
        number2.setOnClickListener(this);
        number3.setOnClickListener(this);
        number4.setOnClickListener(this);
        number5.setOnClickListener(this);
        number6.setOnClickListener(this);
        number7.setOnClickListener(this);
        number8.setOnClickListener(this);
        number9.setOnClickListener(this);
        numberplus.setOnClickListener(this);
        numberminus.setOnClickListener(this);
        numbertimes.setOnClickListener(this);
        numberdiv.setOnClickListener(this);
        numberequal.setOnClickListener(this);
        numberdecimal.setOnClickListener(this);
        text_.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){

            case R.id.btn0:
                text_.append("0");
                break;

            case R.id.btn1:
                text_.append("1");
                break;

            case R.id.btn2:
                text_.append("2");
                break;

            case R.id.btn3:
                text_.append("3");
                break;

            case R.id.btn4:
                text_.append("4");
                break;

            case R.id.btn5:
                text_.append("5");
                break;

            case R.id.btn6:
                text_.append("6");
                break;

            case R.id.btn7:
                text_.append("7");
                break;

            case R.id.btn8:
                text_.append("8");
                break;

            case R.id.btn9:
                text_.append("9");
                break;



            case R.id.btnplus:
                text_.append("+");
                break;

            case R.id.btnminus:
                text_.append("-");
                break;

            case R.id.btndiv:
                text_.append("/");
                break;

            case R.id.btntimes:
                text_.append("*");
                break;

            case R.id.btndecimal:
                text_.append(".");
                break;

            case R.id.btnequal:
                String textString = text_.getText().toString();
                if(textString.contains("+")) {
                    String before = textString.substring(textString.indexOf("+") - 1);
                    String after=textString.substring(textString.indexOf("+") + 1);
                    float number_after=Float.parseFloat(after);
                    float number_before=Float.parseFloat(before);
                    float result = number_before + number_after;
                    String final_result =String.valueOf(result);
                    text_.setText(final_result);

                }
                if(textString.contains("-")) {
                    String before = textString.substring(textString.indexOf("-") - 1);
                    String after=textString.substring(textString.indexOf("-") + 1);
                    float number_after=Float.parseFloat(after);
                    float number_before=Float.parseFloat(before);
                    float result = number_before - number_after;
                    String final_result =String.valueOf(result);
                    text_.setText(final_result);

                }
                if(textString.contains("*")) {
                    String before = textString.substring(textString.indexOf("*") - 1);
                    String after=textString.substring(textString.indexOf("*") + 1);
                    float number_after=Float.parseFloat(after);
                    float number_before=Float.parseFloat(before);
                    float result = number_before * number_after;
                    String final_result =String.valueOf(result);
                    text_.setText(final_result);

                }
                if(textString.contains("/")) {
                    String before = textString.substring(textString.indexOf("/") - 1);
                    String after=textString.substring(textString.indexOf("/") + 1);
                    float number_after=Float.parseFloat(after);
                    float number_before=Float.parseFloat(before);
                    float result = number_before / number_after;
                    String final_result =String.valueOf(result);
                    text_.setText(final_result);

                }

                break;
        }

    }
}
```

If there is any missing information please tell me to add it . Thanks in advance
Edit :
Here is the error :

```
01-31 19:16:11.604 3772-3772/com.example.ahmed.calculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.example.ahmed.calculator, PID: 3772
                                                                            java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5+2"
                                                                                at java.lang.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1306)
                                                                                at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:459)
                                                                                at com.example.ahmed.calculator.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:137)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: If you have numbered variables, that's a sign you need an array/list. In any case, you should set breakpoints in your code and debug it

Comment: You might want to catch the `NumberFornatException` from parsing all those values

Comment: To find the error try this, in the terminal first clear the log before pressing equal buttons. Then press equal button. Redirect log to a file. (I am not sure if android studio, hoping you are using that, by default keeps a log file)...  Let me know if you need the commands, open this log file and search for fatal, you will find the reason for crash

Comment: Thanks all for the help

Comment: @tannitanna  please see the question again i have posted the error. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
here is the issue      

    String before = textString.substring(textString.indexOf("+") - 1);
    String after=textString.substring(textString.indexOf("+") + 1);


if input is "52+34"
before = 2+34
after = 34

Solution


String before = textString.substring(0,textString.indexOf("+"));
String after=textString.substring(textString.indexOf("+"), textString.length());

before = 52
after = 34

rest of the code to get the result looks OK.
```

Answer (score 0):

You did too much copy paste look at your conditions, if you check -,* or / you still splitting your string by '+' instead of - or * or / respectively you need to change that, this way you get index of bounds exception

Comment: Thanks for the help . I have posted the error , any recommendations please ?

Comment: Replace the + character with the - * / respectively inside of each if

Comment: Yes that's what i have did , its just was a typo . I have copied the code from Android studio by mistake here many times , but i have edited the question . Still the error exists and you can find the exception above . I think there is a problem with data types but i cannot know exactly how to fix it .

Comment: Mark vi sign on the left so people will know this problem have been solved